# filter words that contain some letters in a specific order

Tags: python, search, character

In Python, I would like to search through a dictionary such as the Scrabble official list and identify all the words with x number of characters in a particular order. For example, I have "mmt" and would like the output to generate a list of words such as what you see below.

"mmt":

- A**M**ALGA**M**A**T**ED
- A**MM**ONIA**T**ED
- CIRCU**M**A**M**BULA**T**ED
- CO**MM**EN**T**ATED

Thank you!!

Comment: This sounds like a problem for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a dynamic regular expression pattern and filter your list based on that:

```
import re

words = ["AMALGAMATED", "AMMONIATED", "CIRCUMAMBULATED", "COMMENTATED", 
         "TAMTAM", "BLUB", "HOUSE", "SOMETHING"]
filter = "mmt"

regex = re.compile(".*".join(filter), re.IGNORECASE)
filtered_words = [word for word in words if regex.search(word)]

print(*filtered_words, sep="\n")
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/TzKqXu)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking and appreciate it - thank you!